# "How to be back the previous state" is a grammatically right sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

There is a sentence, is it right?

> How to be back to the previous state?

I know that

> How to back to the previous state?

is not grammatically right since here `back` is a transitive verb.

Comment: Hi Alexander! It's probably best to wait a day or two before accepting an answer. This is just because other people might not write more good answers for you if you have already accepted one :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can say:

> How to return to the previous state?
>
> How to get back to the previous state?
>
> How to be back at the previous state?
>
> How to be back in the previous state?

**back** can be a transitive verb but it is not a  transitive verb here. I believe it would be considered a preposition nowadays.

When you return from a trip, you can say:

> I am back.

If you have a headache which goes away after you have taken a couple of aspirin tablets, and the headache later returns, you can say:

> My headache is back.
>
> My headache has come back.